# Django paginate table without get the entire table

Tags: sql, django, database

there is some way to paginate a django model table without get all the db?

Something like

Db => 100 records => [id:0...,id:1...,id:n]

Query => ...?page=1

Return => [id:0...,id:1...,id:25]

Query => ...?page=2

Return => [id:26...,id:27...,id:50]

Answer (score 0):

yes Django have paginator  try this

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import YourModel

def your_view(request):
    # Number of items to display per page
    items_per_page = 25

    # Get the current page from the request's GET parameters
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    # Query all records from your model
    all_records = YourModel.objects.all()

    # Use Paginator to paginate the queryset
    paginator = Paginator(all_records, items_per_page)

    try:
        # Get the records for the requested page
        records = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If the page parameter is not an integer, set it to the first page
        records = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If the page is out of range, deliver the last page of results
        records = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    # Pass the paginated records to the template
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'records': records})
```

in your template.html use this

```
{% for record in records %}
    <!-- Display your record data here -->
{% endfor %}

<!-- Display pagination links -->
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if records.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ records.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ records.number }} of {{ records.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if records.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ records.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ records.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```